# jQuery Firefox ignore null ending

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 inputs with the class `numberchange` and I want to change the input "0.1" so it looks like "0.10"

In chrome the below code-block works fine but Firefox ignores this.

```js
$(".numberchange").change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  val = parseFloat(val).toFixed(2);
  $(this).val(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="minsum" id="minsuminput" step="0.01" Placeholder="Betrag" class="form-control numberchange" />
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Use input type text then.

Comment: Its generaly like that numbers (or input type number) gettin' shortened so theres no fix for that (exept using text input) the problem depends on the browser

Comment: but by type text i dont have the arrows for change

Comment: @Pla558 In generally, customers that use FireFox would be used to how data is displayed in FF, however in cases where users cannot accept browser specific data display we always end up with custom implementations, such as text input , our own arrows buttons and CSS to make it look identical in all browsers. I always would try to not intefer too much with how browsers display or render certain things by default as it can turn into a maintenance nightmare depending how often the browser changes but if you have to, then so be it.

Answer (score 0):

In one word this is happening for only `type="number"`. This will be show as your expected when you change `type="text"`.

Actually this is working fine. When you typing `0.1` then it is dose not matter how many `zero` digit added or not after `.`, this is browser own format but it will work according your expectation.

Suppose when you typing `0.1` it is showing `0.1` (because no difference between `0.1` and `0.10`)

But when you typing:
   `0.135` then it is showing `0.13`